Can I power an AMS1117 5V to 3.3V module with a 9V input?
I'm working on a project where I need to power an ESP-01, which operates at 3.3V. Currently, I'm using a 9V battery as my power source. To step down the voltage, I have an AMS1117 5V to 3.3V module.
My question is about the input voltage for this module. The name of the module suggests that the input should be 5V to get a 3.3V output, but I'm not sure if I can directly connect the 9V battery to it.
Can I power the AMS1117 5V to 3.3V module with a 9V input? Or do I need an additional stage to drop the voltage from 9V to 5V before using the AMS1117?
Thanks in advance for your help.

even a to220 package LDO will get scalding hot at that rate w/o a heatsink, i doubt the little 1117 would last very long, and if it failed, it can deliver 9v to the ESP, frying it. Unless the ESP spends 99% of it's life in deepsleep, you need a beefer LDO.

Yes, you can power it with 9 volt input. It is also on the spec sheet of the module that you linked:

Linear regulators such as the 1117 will heat proportional to the voltage drop and output current. You won't be able to draw the same current as with 5 V input due to overheating.

Based on the datasheet of the regulator on the module you can. Max in voltage is 12V.
Be aware though that power dissipation on the regulator will be (9v-3v3)*I, so around 6x current. If i assume 100mA consumption, this will be 0.6W which is a lot for size of the component you have.
